# Definition of polylog for all complex $\text{z}$

Tags: definition, polylogarithm

What are the different definitions of:

$$\text{Li}_\text{n}\left(\text{z}\right)$$

For all possible $\text{z}$???

I know that when $\left|\text{z}\right|<1$ it is defined by:

$$\text{Li}_\text{n}\left(\text{z}\right)=\sum_{\text{k}=1}^\infty\frac{\text{z}^\text{k}}{\text{k}^\text{n}}$$

Comment: Look at the [Wikipedia Page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) under Integral Representations and Series Representations. Note that all the integrals shown analytically continue the function outside of $|z|<1$, and the same can be done with some series (though that's a topic I leave to the article)

Comment: [PolyLogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).